# Increase javascript variable with html button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I'm trying to increase a javascript variable with a button but it's not working.  This is my code

```
<script src="js/dw_con_scroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var vel = 1;
if ( DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div.isSupported() ) {
        DYN_WEB.Event.domReady( function() {
            var wndo = new DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div('wn', 'lyr1');
            wndo.makeSmoothAuto( {axis:'h', bRepeat:true,repeatId:'rpt1', speed:vel
            , bPauseResume:false,} );
        });
}
document.getElementById("velocita").value = vel;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wn">
   <div id="lyr1">
      <div id="inner1"> 
          <img src="images/1-2.png" width="2000"height="1200" alt="" /><img id="rpt1" src="images/1-2.png" width="2000" height="1200" alt="" />
      </div> 
   </div>
   <button onclick="vel--">-</button><button onclick="vel++">+</button> <input type="text" id="velocita">
   <p><div class="ui button" onClick="parent.location='OKT3-4.html'">Prev</div><div class="ui button" onClick="parent.location='www.google.it'">Next</div></p>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: the value does increase/decrease you just don't see the output anymore.
Put 'document.getElementById("velocita").value = vel;' in a function that you execute onclick after the --/++

Comment: @dwkd well it's not only the output that is not changing. The actual value of the variable is not changing and I'm pretty sure of this because this variable defines the speed of the jquery slider

Comment: you need to instantiate wndo,makeSmoothAuto every time you change vel.. in your example it will not look back on vel change

Comment: @dwkd How can I do that ?

Comment: see my answer .. i hope i got the js in without errors .. i don't have a means to test it, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I believe "onclick" can only link to functions so try something like this:

```
<button onclick="incVel()"> </button>

<script>
function incVel() {
    var vel = document.getElementById("velocita").value;
    vel = vel + 1;
    document.getElementById("velocita").value = vel;
}
</script>

<button onclick="decVel()"> </button>

<script>
function decVel() {
    var vel = document.getElementById("velocita").value;
    vel = vel - 1;
    document.getElementById("velocita").value = vel;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need parentheses if you're going to do this. And this will have the same result as OP's attempt.

Comment: @vitor martins I tried your code but I think JLRishe is right because the variable is not changing.

Comment: I used it and now the speed is actually changing but it seems bugged becuase it speeds up and then stop randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in onClick, like this:

```
   <button onclick="document.getElementById('velocita').value = --vel;">-</button>
   <button onclick="document.getElementById('velocita').value = ++vel;">+</button>
```

Comment: I tried the code and the value in the inputbox is actually changing but the problem is that the "vel" variable (which defines the jquery slider speed) is not really changing because the jquery slider keeps moving at the same speed

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update your value after each button click.

This might solve your problem:

html

```
<button onclick="subtract()">-</button>
<button onclick="add()">+</button>
<input type="text" id="velocita">
```

js

```
var vel = 1;
function subtract() {
    vel--;
    update();
}
function add() {
    vel++;
    update();
}
function update() {
    document.getElementById("velocita").value = vel;
}
update();
```

fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/r1juqut2/

Comment: I tried it and the value in the inputbox is actually changing but it's not changing the speed of the jquery slider which is what I need to do. The vel variable defines the speed of the slider if ( DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div.isSupported() ) {
        DYN_WEB.Event.domReady( function() {
            var wndo = new DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div('wn', 'lyr1');
            wndo.makeSmoothAuto( {axis:'h', bRepeat:true,repeatId:'rpt1', speed:vel
            , bPauseResume:false,} );
        });
}

Comment: You probably need to re-initialize or update the slider with these new properties.

Comment: That's another topic and really depends on what library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems like it is actually incrementing the `vel` variable. I don't have the rep to comment on Vitor's answer, but you can in fact use `onclick` like you are doing, although it is uncommon and I would suggest using Viton Martins' code.

However, it looks like you're trying to display the value of the variable `vel` in an input field:

```
document.getElementById("velocita").value = vel;
```

What's happening here is that this line is executed once when the page is loaded. It is not executed after `vel` is incremented or decremented by your buttons.

To solve this, you'll need to run the line above after every modification of the `vel` variable. Here is an example:

```
<button onclick="addToVel(1)">++</button>
<button onclick="addToVel(-1)">--</button>
<input type="text" id="velocita">

<script>

var vel = 1;
document.getElementById("velocita").value = vel;

function addToVel(amount){
  vel += amount;
  document.getElementById("velocita").value = vel;
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

OP has mentioned in comments that the issue is that the scroller speed is not updating. This is because you only call the function makeSmoothAuto once, and on a variable that is only accessible in the scope of an anonymous function. You'll need to do something like this:

```
var vel = 1;
var wndo;
if ( DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div.isSupported() ) {
        DYN_WEB.Event.domReady( function() {
            wndo = new DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div('wn', 'lyr1');
            wndo.makeSmoothAuto( {axis:'h', bRepeat:true,repeatId:'rpt1', speed:vel
            , bPauseResume:false,} );
        });
}
```

You'll also have to change the `addToVel` function i mentioned before the edit:

```
function addToVel(amount){
  vel += amount;
  document.getElementById("velocita").value = vel;
  wndo.makeSmoothAuto( {axis:'h', bRepeat:true,repeatId:'rpt1', speed:vel
            , bPauseResume:false,} );
}
```

This should both update vel and update your slider at the same time.

Comment: I tried the code and the value in the inputbox is actually changing but the problem is that the "vel" variable (which defines the jquery slider speed)  is not really changing because the jquery slider keeps moving at the same speed

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var vel = 1;
function incrementVel()
{
  vel++;
  initSlider();
  document.getElementById("velocita").value = vel;
}

function decrementVel()
{
  vel--;
  initSlider();
  document.getElementById("velocita").value = vel;
}

function initSlider()
{
  if ( DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div.isSupported() ) {
      DYN_WEB.Event.domReady( function() {
          var wndo = new DYN_WEB.Scroll_Div('wn', 'lyr1');
          wndo.makeSmoothAuto( {axis:'h', bRepeat:true,repeatId:'rpt1', speed:vel
        , bPauseResume:false,} );
      });
  }
}
</script>


<button onclick="decrementVel()">-</button><button onclick="incrementVel()">+</button> <input type="text" id="velocita">
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! is there any chance that the slider doesn't start from the beggingin everytime ? The speed is increasing but everytime i do it , it starts from the beginning

Comment: I am not familiar with this component but try to see if you can resume sliding somehow like jumping to where you left off on the 'h' axis. This means that every time you're done scrolling you need to store the current hAxis position to a global variable declared with vel at the top. Check to see if the widget has a way to define a point where to start on the h axis like ", jumpTo: myLastPoint"

Comment: After some testing I noticed there must be some bug because sometimes it works othertimes it doesn't and the slider is bugging sometimes it stops then runs faster

Comment: I think we're well beyond the scope of the initial question and I can't help without a proper documentation of the component, the code and its intent.